# Cannot debug Boost multi Array in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-debugging, boost-multi-array

Suppose I were to define a std::vector, and push some elements into it. During the course of debugging, I can inspect all the elements inside my vector from the watch window. This way, I can find out if some of the elements of the std::vector have been assigned an incorrect value.

However, when using a Boost multiarray, there seems to be no means available to inspect the elements of the multiarray from the debug watch window. The watch window shows me some weird fields like base, allocator, etc, but there is no data field that displays the values of elements of the container.

So, my question is, is there a way to inspect the elements of a boost multiarray from Visual Studio 2010 debugger watch window?

Comment: Does it give you a reason or messages? There isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: Suppose I were to define a std::vector, and push some elements into it. If, during the course of debugging, I hover my house over the std::vector, the Visual Studio debugging utility attempts to show me all the elements inside my vector. This way, I can find out if some of the elements of the std::vector have been assigned an incorrect value. The same can be done from the watch window.
But, with the boost multi-arrays, when I hover my mouse on it, it shows me some weird fields for the container, viz. 'allocator_', 'base_', but it does not show me the values for the elements of the container.

Comment: No, there are no error messages.

Comment: I still dont understand why my initial question was not clear to you all. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I think you can write Visual Studio plugins to do this for you. Not an answer as I have no idea about the details.

Comment: What is going on with std::vector is that the IDE has special handling added for all the standard library data types, so they can be displayed nicely in the debugger. The actual data structures are not nearly so pretty.